# How do I delete my commands quickly?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

I use terminal for almost all tasks. Let's say I have entered a huge command like this:

```
sudo a-huge-command
```

What is the easiest way to delete the whole command with a single shortcut, rather than keep on hitting <kbd>backspace</kbd> key?

I'm a Ubuntu newbie looking to use Ubuntu in a professional way.

Comment: It's also worthwhile to note that you can set `bash` (and several other shells) to understand vi keys: `set -o vi`. You could then do `esc`, `dd` (or otherwise edit/replace as you could do in vi[m]).

Comment: Home, '#', Enter

Comment: this is a cheap hack but for what it's worth, I usually just hit up-arrow until I get to a really short command (e.g., `ls`)and then backspace - this usually only a couple of key strokes so it isn't that big a' deal.

Comment: CTRL <-  tapped a couple of times usually lets me go back to the beginning of my query.. is this what you mean ?

Answer (score 181, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to cut text from cursor position to the beginning of the command line. Later, if you want, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> to paste the cut text.

If you just want to discard the current command line and get a new clean prompt hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

For more reference please check the Ubuntu  documentation for [Using The Terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal)

Comment: This answer works for both bash (Ubuntu default) and tsch.

Comment: I thought dash was Ubuntu default?

Comment: `dash` is the default interpreter for `/bin/sh` commands. `bash` is the default login and TTY shell.

Comment: I find `Ctrl + C` to be a bad habit, since I'll often accidentally send signals to programs with their own prompt, killing them and losing my progress and/or momentum.

Answer (score 114):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>U</kbd> should help you.

Below are the rest of the options available.
Grabbed from [here](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~rootd/catdoc/guide/TheGuide_38.html)

UNIX understands several control-key commands, commands you enter by holding down the control key (ctrl) while striking a second key

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> +  <kbd>S</kbd> - freezes the screen and stops any display on the screen from continuing
(equivalent to a no-scroll key) (sometimes takes a moment to work)

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> - un-freezes the screen and lets screen display continue

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> +  <kbd>C</kbd> - interrupts a running program

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> +  <kbd>\</kbd> - same as CTRL -  C but stronger (used when terminal doesn't respond)

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> +  <kbd>Z</kbd> - suspends a running program (use the fg command to continue the program, see s$

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> +  <kbd>H</kbd> - deletes last character typed

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> +  <kbd>W</kbd> - deletes last word typed

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> +  <kbd>U</kbd> - deletes last line typed

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> +  <kbd>R</kbd> - searches text from history

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> +  <kbd>D</kbd> - ends text input for many UNIX programs, including mail and write.

Note:

When we delete using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>, we are also performing a (edit) "cut" (yank in) operation (delete and store in buffer/clipboard). To paste (yank out) the string in buffer/clipboard, use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>.

Comment: Actually ctrl-r searches text from history.

Comment: @EricCarvalho You are right. Removing that option from the answer.

Comment: These are generic UNIX control codes. The default ubuntu terminal is bash-based, which is different.

Comment: Ctrl-U deletes from the cursor to the beginning of the line.  I often use it by placing the cursor just before the arguments to a command from history.  That way, I can type a new command using the same arguments - like changing less file to kate file so I can edit the file after I've looked at it to see if any edits are needed.

Comment: @OrangeDog  -- These are fine -- I use all of these in my Ubuntu bash-bashed terminal, with the exception of the CTR-\ one.

Answer (score 61):

I'm usually using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>. If you are using `bash`, this will let you delete untill the previous special character (`/`, `;`, , etc.). If you are using `zsh`, it will remove the slashes and semicolons as well. It is a lot faster than just hitting <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

In `bash`, this is different from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> in the sense that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> deletes the previous word wheres <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> deletes until the previous special character is found. In `zsh`, both key combinations do the same thing

Comment: Ctrl+W does the same thing.

Comment: Won't work for terminals such as rxvt though.

Comment: @lyrae For me it works perfectly in rxvt, though not in xterm. And it only works if `set -o emacs` is set.

Comment: I use `ALT+Backspace` as well as `CTRL+C`. This works on any linux. :)

Comment: @hakermania: No, its different. Ctrl + w deletes a word and Alt + Backspace deletes until the previous special character(`/`, `;`, ` `, etc).

Answer (score 38):

Here is a [listing](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/keyboard-shortcuts-for-bash-command-shell-for-ubuntu-debian-suse-redhat-linux-etc/) of keyboard shortcuts that can be used with the `bash` shell.

```
Ctrl + A    Go to the beginning of the line you are currently typing on
Ctrl + E    Go to the end of the line you are currently typing on
Ctrl + L    Clears the Screen, similar to the clear command
Ctrl + U    Clears the line before the cursor position. If you are at the end of the line, clears the entire line.
Ctrl + H    Same as backspace
Ctrl + R    Lets you search through previously used commands
Ctrl + C    Kill whatever you are running or start a new prompt
Ctrl + D    Exit the current shell
Ctrl + Z    Puts whatever you are running into a suspended background process. fg restores it.
Ctrl + W    Delete the word before the cursor
Ctrl + K    Clear the line after the cursor
Ctrl + T    Swap the last two characters before the cursor
Esc + T     Swap the last two words before the cursor
Alt + F     Move cursor forward one word on the current line
Alt + B     Move cursor backward one word on the current line
Tab         Auto-complete files and folder names
```

What you are wanting to do is achieved by either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> at the end of the line.

Comment: This is the most-complete list, Though the best answer is `Ctrl+C` or (`Ctrl+E` `Ctrl+U`)

Comment: How many on the list are applicable to tcsh, which I'm interested in?

Comment: @shan23 Read the "Editor commands" section of `man tcsh`, or use `bindkey -l`. It looks like it's very different.

Comment: Note that some of these will fail if you're using vi bindings for bash's (or another shell's) Readline.  These should mostly apply to tcsh as well; these pre-dated bash. bash also incorporated a lot of the nice history shortcuts from csh/tcsh.

Answer (score 25):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd> (i.e., <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>) will comment out the current command and continue on the next line.

For example, if you type <kbd>t</kbd>, <kbd>e</kbd>, <kbd>s</kbd>, <kbd>t</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd>, you'll get:

```
you@computer$ #test
you@computer$
```

If you want to get your old command back, you can press the up arrow and delete the hash character (<kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>Delete</kbd> or <kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Delete</kbd>).

I think it's a feature of [GNU Readline](http://www.gnu.org/software/readline/), since it works in Bash, Python, and MySQL.

Answer (score 24):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> - in addition to interrupting running commands, it may be used to "interrupt" your command line input as well.

In contrast to the  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>, you will still see what you have typed but your cursor will jump to the new line and you will get an empty command line prompt.

Comment: I prefer this simply because of muscle memory, and you can still copy/paste anything important because the aborted command-line stays there.

Answer (score 8):

The Bash `readline` shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> is very useful indeed when you are working on the command-line. If you are in the process of entering a long command and decide that you want to instead open it in your default text editor, all you have to do is use the shortcut.

It makes use of Bash's `readline` library and this particular shortcut is called the `edit-and-execute-command`.  You can set your default editor by placing `export EDITOR="/usr/bin/vi"` in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases`.

Enter `bind -P` to see your current `readline` bindings and refer to `man readline` or the [Ubuntu manpages online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man3/readline.3readline.html) for more information.

Answer (score 7):

I also use <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> to delete all previous characters until a special character. This is same is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>.  Handy if you're just deleting a few words at a time.

Answer (score 3):

## For `vi` key bindings

When usin a `vi` key map like in `bash` with `set -o vi` or in `zsh` with `bindkey -v`:

### Insert mode

It is just the same keystroke as in default/emacs mode:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>

deleting form the current position to the start of line. So it deletes the whole line if the cursor is at the end.

### Normal mode

There are multiple ways to delete the line in two keystrokes:

Delete linewise `dd`, with the default count of one line:

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>

which is the simplest in terms of keys touched.

Another way is: Go to start of line with `^`, and delete to the end of line with `D`:

<kbd>^</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>

These both delete the entire line, not only to the left, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> in insert mode, or the variant bleow.

If you are at the end of line currently, so you do not need to delete anything to the right, this would also do:

Delete from here `d`, to start of line `^`:

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>^</kbd>

You can use these all from inset mode, you need the usual escape first to go to normal mode. For example to delete the whole line from insert mode, use:

<kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>