# Which bash shortcuts/tips are available?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

Depending on his type of usage, an Ubuntu user may spend a lot of time in front of a terminal. Knowing some keyboard shortcuts can make you save a lot of time (ex: copy/paste text, move between the prompt text, etc).

So which bash tips/shortcuts do you guys know?

Comment: Are we really talking about "terminals" here or shells? [There's a big difference.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con)

Comment: I was asking for tips to help improve usage on gnome terminal or tty's ("black screens with a blinking cursor" :)). Would "bash shortcuts/tips" be more accurate? I have only used bash so I really don't know if those tips apply to other shells.

Comment: I'm really on edge about whether this should be closed or not... But I'll leave it open for now.

Comment: See [this popular question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/183933/how-do-i-delete-my-commands-quickly) for all manner of shortcuts, just like the ones mentioned here.

Comment: Most of the shortcuts listed in the first answer below apply to Bash and not the terminal.

Comment: And of course now I'm on the fence about whether this should be reopened or not...

Answer (score 4):

#### Output management

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd> - Scrolling the terminal output. This is very handy when using an *tty*: in Gnome Terminal works the same way as dragging the scroolbar.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> - Pauses the output: the command keeps running, only their output stops.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> - Resume the output: when output is paused, this will make the command show their output again.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> - Clear terminal output.

---

#### Prompt text manipulation

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> - Deletes all the text currently typed in the prompt.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> - Deletes all the text from the right of the cursor
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> - Deletes a word, from right to left.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> - Move to the beginning of the text.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> - Move to the end of the typed text.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> arrow - Move to the beginning/end of the previous/next word.

---

#### Command execution

- <kbd>Tab</kbd> - Lists available commands from the typed text.
- <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> arows - Shows previous/next command executed.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> - Searches the last command executed from the given text.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> - Stops the current command.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> - Sends the program to the background. Can then be managed using `fg`/`jobs`.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> - Logs out from the current terminal. Similar to typing `exit`.

Answer (score 3):

There are many more, but ones I use a lot:

- Repeat/insert the previous command: `!!`

  ```
  $ which rename
  /usr/bin/rename
  $ file $(!!)
  file $(which rename)
  /usr/bin/rename: symbolic link to `/etc/alternatives/rename'
  ```
- Select words from the previous command: `!:1`, `!:2`, etc.

  ```
  $ ls /var/lib/logrotate/*
  /var/lib/logrotate/status
  $ cat !:1
  cat /var/lib/logrotate/*
  ... contents ...
  ```
- Fix typo in previous command: `^x^y` and `^x`

  ```
  $ lls
  lls: command not found
  $ ^l 
  ls 
  ... listing ...
  $ ^s^l
  ll
  ... long listing ...
  ```